# Error in OpenERP

Tags: python

I have some problem with my project:

```
def get_timein(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    timein = str(datetime.now())
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'time_in':timein }, context=context)
    return 1

def get_timeout(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    obj=self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    timeout=str(datetime.now())
    self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'time_out':timeout }, context=context)
    return 1

def cho_dangnhap(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'dangnhap'})
    get_timein(cr,uid,ids)
    return 1

def cho_rave(self, cr, uid, ids, context={}):
    self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr, uid, ids, {'state':'rave'})
    get_timeout(cr, uid, ids)
```

I am getting this error:

```
NameError: global name 'get_timeout' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def cho_dangnhap(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
            self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'dangnhap'})
            self.get_timein(cr,uid,ids)
            return 1
def cho_rave(self,cr,uid,ids,context={}):
            self.pool.get('x_luong').write(cr,uid,ids,{'state':'rave'})
            self.get_timeout(cr,uid,ids)
```

The `self.` before method functions is required.

Comment: how can i fix it?? help me please thanks. I am learning about open erp. It's so difference

Comment: @ThongTran: Step 1.  Compare my code with your code.  Character-by-character if it helps.  Step 2: Enumerate the differences carefully.  There are two copies of `self.` in my code that are important.  Step 3: Apply those changes to your code.